# Spin-lock implementation

Tags: locking, go

I'm working on a project where a spinlock is more appropriate than a mutex, and after few tries I came up with:

```
type SpinLock uint32

func (sl *SpinLock) Lock() {
    for !atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32((*uint32)(sl), 0, 1) {
        runtime.Gosched() //without this it locks up on GOMAXPROCS > 1
    }
}

func (sl *SpinLock) Unlock() {
    atomic.StoreUint32((*uint32)(sl), 0)
}
```

It works fine, and it's even a little bit faster than `sync.Mutex`, and 2x the speed of `sync.RWMutex`.

```
➜ go test -bench=. -benchmem -v -cpu 4
BenchmarkSpinL-4            2000           1078798 ns/op           33923 B/op       2006 allocs/op
BenchmarkMutex-4            2000           1195814 ns/op           32781 B/op       2002 allocs/o
BenchmarkRWMutex-4          1000           2352117 ns/op           78253 B/op       2147 allocs/op
```

The test uses multi readers / writers to a `map[int]*struct{int, int}`. Running it with `-race` doesn't detect any data races, either.

But I have that nagging feeling that I forgot something, so I'm wondering if my implementation is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only weak point is that the implementation is not copy safe nor there exist mechanism for ensuring copy protection. I would hide its underlying type and return as `sync.Locker`, so it can't be mis-used:

```
type spinLock uint32

func (sl *spinLock) Lock() {
    for !atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32((*uint32)(sl), 0, 1) {
        runtime.Gosched() //without this it locks up on GOMAXPROCS > 1
    }
}

func (sl *spinLock) Unlock() {
    atomic.StoreUint32((*uint32)(sl), 0)
}

func SpinLock() sync.Locker {
    return &spinLock{}
}
```

An alternative I've seen in `sync.Cond` is to [embed an auxiliary type for copy-protection](http://golang.org/src/pkg/sync/cond.go#L112), although it would complicate the implementation unnecessary.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Code Review, and congratulations on passing through the 'Late Answer' review queue. Nice answer to an older question.

Comment: you use the `SpinLock` function instantiate and return the `spinLock` (a `sync.Locker`) using composite literal notation (`return &spinLock{}`), but this inappropriate for the underlying type and so [the compiler throws an error]( https://play.golang.org/p/qtxa5zYD1b_N). If the `spinLock` is instead instantiated via another method, such as `return new(spinLock)`, then the compiler is happy. [Here's a link to an example that compiles.](https://play.golang.org/p/U5Z-vVnQayZ)